# Sublime Text - How do I create a keyboard shortcut to move text from one open file to another

Tags: sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text, I've got blocks of text in a column on the left and I'd like to selectively shift some lines to a separate file on the right.

Is there an existing keyboard shortcut to do this, and if not how would I go about putting one together. The steps would be

```
1. Cut selection
2. Change to other column
3. Paste selection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple plugin that meets your question's requirements and has a few extra features:

- bidirectional `copy` & `cut` commands ( *from active document to inactive document, works on either view* )
- selects & scrolls to inserted text @ inactive document
- only executes if there are exactly 2 view groups

[image: Demo]

---

Copy the following code to:
`Packages/MoveTextToInactiveDocument/MoveTextToInactiveDocument.py`

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin

LINE_BREAK = "\n"

class MoveTextToInactiveDocumentCommand( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit, MODE = "copy" ):

        view   = self.view
        window = view.window()

        #■■■  Verify Window Groups  ■■■#

        windowGroup_Count = window.num_groups()

        if windowGroup_Count != 2:
            return

        #■■■  Set Active & Inactive Documents  ■■■#

        activeDocument_Group = window.active_group()

        if activeDocument_Group == 0:
            activeDocument   = window.active_view_in_group( 0 )
            inactiveDocument = window.active_view_in_group( 1 )
        elif activeDocument_Group == 1:
            activeDocument   = window.active_view_in_group( 1 )
            inactiveDocument = window.active_view_in_group( 0 )

        #■■■  Verify Selection  ■■■#

        selections = activeDocument.sel()

        if len( selections ) == 0:
            return

        #■■■  Move Text From Active Document To Inactive Document  ■■■#

        first_InsertionPoint = inactiveDocument.size()

        for region in selections:

            regionText     = activeDocument.substr( region ) + LINE_BREAK
            insertionPoint = inactiveDocument.size()

            inactiveDocument.insert( edit, insertionPoint, regionText )

            if MODE.lower() == "cut":
                activeDocument.erase( edit, region )

        #■■■  Select & Scroll To Inserted Text  ■■■#

        inactiveDocument_End = inactiveDocument.size()
        insertedText_Region  = sublime.Region( first_InsertionPoint, inactiveDocument_End )

        inactiveDocument.selection.clear()
        inactiveDocument.selection.add( insertedText_Region )

        inactiveDocument.show( inactiveDocument.size() )
        window.focus_view( activeDocument )
```

---

Open your user `sublime-keymap` file by running `Preferences: Key Bindings - User` from the `command palette`.

Add the following `key-bindings`.

```json
{
    "keys": [ "ctrl+super+c" ],
    "command": "move_text_to_inactive_document",
    "args": { "MODE": "Copy" }
},

{
    "keys": [ "ctrl+super+x" ],
    "command": "move_text_to_inactive_document",
    "args": { "MODE": "Cut" }
},
```

---

You can now use:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Super + C</kbd> to copy selections to the inactive document
- <kbd>Ctrl + Super + X</kbd> to cut selections to the inactive document

Comment: This is great @Enteleform. Thank you. The code is very easy to understand too so doubly helpful.